# SQL Server 2012 which user is using Memory and CPU

Tags: performance, sql-server-2012

For sql server 2012 I am looking for a way to see which active user logins are using how much memory and cpu.  I have done a search but it seems there is only a way to see aggregates or how much each database uses for memory.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sp_who2 can provide some information.

But generally the question makes no sense for memory. Memory is MOTLY used as page cache and that is never user specific but always database specific. A data page in the database is not owned by a user. They also get dropped as needed and are kept as long as possible - so if you try to find out why your server uses so much memory, totally wrong approach.

Similar for CPU - that is a question of query efficiency. It should not be started from the user, but from the SQL query. A specifi user may execute a crappy SQL query that burns tons of CPU, but it is not the fault of the user and you CAN see which sql statements blow all the CPU in terms of processing efficiency.

Answer (score 1):

run sp_who2 active to see all active usage.